# Aquatic Animals Start A Movement

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

```
Aquatic animals start a movement
But do not even move an inch
They say it is a word split into three
But we ducks do not see
The entire word, they say,
Is an unfriendly prig
I did not believe a word they said
Until they offered some bread
```

Help me get the bread!

Hint 1:

> The description of the phrase of the three words only takes up the first line. Try to substitute the words for others and join them to get the full word. Also, not many words fit line 6 that have three words in them.

Hint 2:

> It is 11 letters long.

Hint 3:

> The first word inside is 5 letters long, the second 2, and the last 4.

Comment: ROT13(Gur gvgyr pbhyq ersre gb gur "Ndhnevhz", juvpu vf bar zbirzrag sebz gur Pneaniny bs gur Navznyf ol Fnvag-Fnraf. Gur ndhngvp navznyf "qb abg zbir na vapu": gurl fgnaq gurer, rnpu bar cynlvat gurve vafgehzrag.)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier This is another 'word split into three' puzzle (the last one being the First of Three) kind of like a Riley riddle, the second line is to **clarify** that a movement does not mean moving around and the title and first line describe the three words in the word that make the phrase.

Comment: Is this hint not *too* explicit?

Comment: @Certainlynotadog See 'The First of Three' (by clicking on my account or searching it on the search bar.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are

> **STANDOFFISH**

*Aquatic animals*

> OF FISH

*start a movement*
*but do not move an inch*

> STAND

*They say it is a word split into three*

> It's a standing of the fish - a STAND OF FISH

*The entire word, they say,*
*Is an unfriendly prig*

> If someone is standoffish, they are distant, cold, and/or unfriendly

*I did not believe a word they said*
*Until they offered some bread*

> Mmm, tasty :)

Comment: Nice job! Correct!

Comment: Thanks for the bread! Now those fish won't bother me!

Comment: @Duck Any more puzzles fermenting in your brain? :)

Comment: Not yet, but I'll try!